# Join statement and comparison

Tags: sql, join

The database being used for this question is structured as follows with Primary Keys bolded, and Foreign Keys ' '.

---

Countries (Name, **Country_ID**, area_sqkm, population)

Teams (**team_id**, name, 'country_id', description, manager)

Stages (**stage_id**, took_place, start_loc, end_loc, distance, description)

Riders (**rider_id**, name, 'team_id', year_born, height_cms, weight_kgs, 'country_id', bmi)

Results ('**stage_id**', '**rider_id**', time_seconds)

---

I am stuck at the question of:

Q: Bradley Wiggins won the tour. Write a query to find the riders who beat him in at least 4 stages, i.e., riders who had a better time than Wiggins in at least 4 of the 21 stages.

I am currently at :

```
SELECT ri.name
from riders ri
INNER JOIN results re ON ri.name = re.name
WHERE ri.name = 'BRADLEY Wiggins' IN ...`
```

I am unsure of how can I move to comparing 2 time_seconds.

May I know how can I go about getting the solution?

Thank you

Comment: School work? Check out GROUP BY and count(*).

Comment: `JOIN results re ON ri.name = re.name` is not going to fly, since the `result` table has no such column `name`. Try `JOIN results re ON ri.id = re.rider_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is indeed a little complicated, as it involves several concepts.

The first of these is a self join, i.e. you'll have to select from the same table twice. You want Bradley's results and the others' results, so as to be able to compare them.

```
select ...
from results bradley
join results other on ...
```

Or:

```
select ...
from (select * from results where ...) bradley
join (select * from results where ...) other on ...
```

Let's use the first option. We add a WHERE clause so to get Bradley and we add the ON clause to get non-Bradleys at the same stage with a better result:

```
select ...
from results bradley
join results other on other.rider_id <> bradley.rider_id
                   and other.stage_id = bradley.stage_id
                   and other.time_seconds < bradley.time_seconds
where bradley.rider_id = (select id from riders where name = 'BRADLEY Wiggins')
```

The last part is to find riders with at least four better results. This is called aggregation. You want to see riders, so you group by rider_id. And you want to count, so you use COUNT. Moreover you want to restrict results based on COUNT, so you put this in the HAVING clause:

```
select other.rider_id
from results bradley
join results other on other.rider_id <> bradley.rider_id
                   and other.stage_id = bradley.stage_id
                   and other.time_seconds < bradley.time_seconds
where bradley.rider_id = (select id from riders where name = 'BRADLEY Wiggins')
group by other.rider_id
having count(*) >= 4;
```

As to getting the riders' data, e.g. their names, there are a couple of options:

1. Join the table and put the columns both in your SELECT clause and your GROUP BY clause. You would do this, if you wanted data from both sets, i.e. riders' data plus the result count.
2. Subselect the value if you only want one value (e.g. the name). That's simple but really only makes sense when you want only one value from riders table.

You'd change your SELECT clause thus:

```
select (select name from riders where id = other.rider_id) as name
```

3. Write an outer query around the query you already have.

This would be:

```
select *
from riders
where id in
(
  select other.rider_id
  from results bradley
  join results other on other.rider_id <> bradley.rider_id
                     and other.stage_id = bradley.stage_id
                     and other.time_seconds < bradley.time_seconds
  where bradley.rider_id = (select id from riders where name = 'BRADLEY Wiggins')
  group by other.rider_id
  having count(*) >= 4
);
```